# Opening PDF and other attachments in QField

Tags: qgis, pdf, qfield

I want to open a PDF file in QField, but I don't know how to configure a project to be created in QGIS.

Can you tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can open local or online files referenced by relative path or weblink with the attachement widget in QField.

Configuration in QGIS:
[image: attachementwidget]

You can also add / change pictures in QField. But other file types (like PDF) are currently read only.